# Chrome extension send selected text to an external API via POST

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Here is my popup.js file

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
    code: "window.getSelection().toString();"
}, function(selection) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = selection[0];
});
```

How do I send selected text along with the url to an external API via POST request?

Comment: Add the API url in manifest.json "permissions" and do the post request as usual. You can easily find lots of examples. To debug, rightclick the popup and click inspect - it'll open the popup's devtools.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks! I tried and found this error on console 'Failed to load http://localhost:8000/api/excerpt/: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'chrome-extension://jpcxxx..m' is therefore not allowed access."

Answer (score 0):

Following code was able to send POST requests to an external API

**popup.js:**

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
    code: "window.getSelection().toString();"
}, function(selection) {
    //document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = selection[0];
    var data = "quote=This%20is%20%dope%20feature%20with%20embed%20option";

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;

    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
      if (this.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
      }
    });

    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8000/api/excerpt/");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Token 42f2909aeacc293ac3a33a76485821e6399d5e1472");

    xhr.send(data);    
});
```